# Inclusion and belonging

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've started study some set theory and U have a doubt.

I understand that inclusion doesn't imply belonging: {4} ⊆ {4}, but {4} not-∈ to {4}.

My question is: if a set, X, is such that X ∈ Y, does this imply that X ⊆ Y? Could explain it using also some examples?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you're correct, these are two different concepts. in particular $X\in Y$ does *not* imply $X\subseteq Y$, for example $4\in\{4\}$ but not $4\subseteq\{4\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=\{2,3\}\,$ and $\,Y=\big\{\{2,3\},\{7,8\}\big\}.$

Then Y has four subsets:

- $\big\{\{2,3\},\{7,8\}\big\},$
- $\emptyset,$
- $\big\{\{2,3\}\big\},$
- $\big\{\{7,8\}\big\}.$

Evidently, $X\in Y,$ but $X \not\subseteq Y.$

P.S. Note that the first three sets above have $2$ elements each, the fourth set is empty, and the last two sets have $1$ element each.